# Difference between xargs and GNU parallel

Tags: xargs, gnu-parallel

I need to run an executable a large number of times, each time with two command line arguments. I've used to use `xargs` for this purpose, but lately I've been made aware of the existence of GNU `parallel`, which in principle seems like a better tool (more features, more up-to-date, more extensive documentation, etc.).

Also, a strong selling point for me was the claim that it can be used as "a drop in replacement for `xargs`" (https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/history.html). However, I'm having a bit of trouble with that last point.

Say that I have a text file, `args.txt`, with several lines, where each line contains two numbers separated by a space, for example:

```
1 2
7 9
11 13
```

I want to run my program, `run`, once for each line (i.e., once for each pair of arguments). With `xargs` I would do

```
cat args.txt | xargs -n2 run
```

where `-n2` indicates that `xargs` should pass 2 arguments to `run` at each invocation. `xargs` then interprets each number as one argument, so each line of `args.txt` is interpreted as two arguments.

However, when I try using `parallel` as a drop-in replacement for `xargs` in the case above, I get different behaviour.

To illustrate, I will use the following small python script in place of my program run:

printer.py:

```
import sys
print([x for x in sys.argv[1:]])
```

Now, with xargs I get:

```
> cat args.txt | xargs -n2 python printer.py

['1', '2']
['7', '9']
['11', '13']
```

while with `parallel` I get

```
> cat args.txt | parallel -n2 python printer.py

['1 2', '7 9']
['11 13']
```

So while `xargs` calls the python script with the individual (space-separated) numbers as arguments, `parallel` interprets instead each line as a single argument, meaning that for example at the first call, the first argument is `"1 2"` instead of just `"1"`.

I'm a little bit confused by this, as I had expected `parallel` to work as a drop-in replacement for `xargs`, but apparently it's a bit more subtle than that. I suppose my question is how I should use `parallel` to achieve the same thing that I'm doing with `xargs`, but I'm also just curious about why there is a difference in behaviour here, and if it's intentional.

Comment: You could try `cat args.txt | parallel --colsep ' ' python printer.py` if separator is always one space. Regexp is also possible.

Comment: This works nicely, thanks! I actually tried ```--colsep``` before, but I also kept ```-n2```, which didn't work. But your suggestion does exactly what I want. If you post it as an answer I'll mark it as the accepted solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have hit one of the few incompatibilities between `xargs` and `parallel` which is by design.

GNU Parallel will make sure the input is quoted as a single argument, whereas xargs will not. It was one of the original driving forces for writing the first versions of GNU Parallel.

```
$ echo '9" nails in 10" boxes' | xargs echo
9 nails in 10 boxes
$ echo '9" nails in 10" boxes' | parallel echo
9" nails in 10" boxes
```

You can, however, force GNU Parallel not to quote the input:

```
cat args.txt | parallel python printer.py {=uq=}
```

This will take one line from `args.txt` and insert it in the command without quoting it.

(Version 20190722 or later).

Another option is to split the columns on a single space (as mentioned in the comments):

```
cat args.txt | parallel --colsep ' ' python printer.py
```

Or white space:

```
cat args.txt | parallel --colsep '\s+' python printer.py
```

(Version 20100822 or later).

Answer (score 1):

Parallel reads the input a line at a time, unlike xargs which reads words.

You can achieve the same result like this:

```
> sed 's/\s\+/\n/g' args.txt | parallel -n2 python printer.py
```

Here, the `sed` tool converts all groups of white-space into a line break.